# Output in a form format that can be submitted after reading from a text file

Tags: html, output, submission, forms, http-post

I have the following text file:

```
$string = 
'1 The most important feature of spiral model is: requirement analysis. risk    management. quality management. configuration management 2 The worst type of coupling is: Data coupling. control coupling. stamp coupling. content coupling 3 One of the fault base testing techniques is: unit testing. beta testing. Stress testing. mutation testing 4 A fault simulation testing technique is: Mutation testing. Stress testing. Black box testing. White box testing 5 RS is also known as: specification of White box testing. Stress testing. Integrated testing. Black box testing 6 what is you name: Collins. Achieng. Ogwethi. Kamanda';
```

The following codes read the text file and the output in a form format with a pull down menu to select the multiple question. This is how I'm trying to go about it,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>read</title>
</head>
<body>
    <b><u> QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS QUIZ</u></b> <br /><br />
<?php
$openFile = fopen("questionandanswers.txt", "r") or exit ("unable to open the text       file");
$string = fread($openFile, filesize("questionandanswers.txt"));

//Regex to get from the first number to the string's end, so we ignore the Number     Question... bit;
preg_match('/\d.*/', $string, $match);

//We get all the strings starting with a number until it finds another number (which will be the beginning of another question;
preg_match_all('/\d\D*/', $match[0], $results);

$qas = array(); // We prepare an array with all the questions/answers
foreach($results[0] as $result){
//Separating the answer from the string with all the answers.
list($question, $all_answers) = explode(':', $result);

//Separating the different answers
$answers_array = explode('.', $all_answers);

//Stuffing the question and the array with all the answers into the previously prepared   array;
$qas[] = array('question' => $question, 'answers' => $answers_array);
}
?>
<form name="processor" action="processor.php" method="post">
<?php
//Looping through the array and outputting all the info into a form;
foreach($qas as $k => $v)?>
echo "<label>{$v['question']}</label><br/>";
echo "<select name='answers[]'>";

//we loop through $v['answers'] because its an array within the array with all the    answers.
foreach($v['answers'] as $answer)
{
    echo "<option>$answer</option>";//the output
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<br/><br/>";
?>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to submit the output to another php file that processes the output as $_POST. Anybody who can assist me through this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to correct this line:

```
echo "<select>";
```

to:

```
echo "<select name='answers[]'>";
```

In the processor.php file you will then be able to select all answers as an array:

```
var_dump($_POST['answers'])
```

But you should rethink this line as it seems to corrupt the document model:

```
<input type="text" name="question" value="<?
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight, I seem not to get how it will integrate with my code, would you please assist me in integrating the same. because after inputting the corrections you highlighted I still get the same errors. Thank you.

Comment: It erases my previously created form and displays a distorted form with some parts of the codes displayed on the browser. I don't know how I can link it here for you to see the exact output, but that's just an explanation of what happens when I try to run it on my local server

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of it?

Comment: I have the screen shot, This might be naive, but I don't know where to upload it on this site.

Comment: I'm still not qualified to upload the screen shot.

Comment: If u may run the codes in your computer, you will experience what I am talking about. Thank you.